# Redirect One Multisite to Another

Tags: multisite, redirect

A friend's  multisite ise set up using directory structure and she just wants to have the URLs for an older subsite to a newer one, say `http://www.coolstuff.foo/abcd` to redirect to `http://www.coolstuff.foo/zxcv`

What I have tried that has not worked includes:

- setting up a redirect in cpanel
- adding an htaccess `RewriteRule ^abcd/(.*)$ /zxcv/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`
- trying a redirect plugin

I thought this was a 5 minute thing and I'm an hour in! I am missing something obvious for sure

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the **beginning** of the .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abcd/(.*)$ /zxcv/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```